# Erro para Importação de JDBC do sqlServer com Maven

Tags: java, sql-server, java-ee, maven, jdbc

Na minha aplicação java web ,precisei acrescentar uma conexão com um banco sql server, então coloquei como dependência do maven  como descrito abaixo:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

A dependência foi baixada e se encontra dentro da pasta m2.

Rodando a aplicação localmente na minha máquina , tudo funciona com o código de importação abaixo:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
```

Porém, após gerar o **WAR** do projeto com o comado  `mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pdev`  e publicado dentro de um servidor de desenvolvimento, tenho o seguinte erro:

> Root cause of ServletException. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver

Acredito que , ou eu esteja importando errado no código ou esqueci de configurar alguma coisa para o maven.

Verifiquei, também, que após rodado o comando do maven a dependência é colocada dentro de `WEB-INF\lib` conforme as outras dependências, mas minha aplicação não encontra, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Neste servidor de desenvolvimento, não há outro JAR adicionado com mesmo nome em uma versão mais antiga? Está usando Tomcat?

Comment: Para rodar local utilizo tomcat, mas no servidor de desenvvolvimento a qual publiquei é weblogic

Comment: Verifica se não tem neste weblogic um driver já adicionado com o mesmo nome. Pode ser que dois JARs com o mesmo nome existam em versões diferentes, aí no classpath o primeiro deles é considerado e, talvez, esteja ocorrendo de encontrar o antigo antes. Este pacote mudou de uma versão para outra, por isto acho que é uma possibiidade.

Comment: Entendi, irei verificar. Outra dúvida, esses JARS após o build pelo maven vão para a pasta WEB-INF/lib e aplicação irá "ler" desta pasta ou da pasta  de JARS do servidor?

Comment: Das duas. Dependendo do servidor de aplicação, inclusive tem a opção de você escolher entre tentar encontrar as dependências primeiro no próprio servidor e depois dentro da aplicação (e vice-versa), para driblar este tipo de problema que comentei anteriormente. Acredito que o weblogic tenha este controle, inclusive (se tiver), você pode experimentar de alterar para seu deploy isto, mas não posso te dizer como pq não conheço WebLogic

Comment: Mas se fosse dentro da aplicação o caminho de import seria o mesmo?
"com.microsoft....."

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81221/discussion-between-dherik-and-felipe).

Answer (score 0):

Eu passei por este mesmo problema no passado e resolvi da seguinte maneira:

Acrescente o código abaixo em seu código de conexão:

```
static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("SQLServer DataSource unable to load SQLServer Driver");
    }
}
```